# Magento2 error when trying to create a record in db

Tags: magento2, module, database, magento-2.0, crud

I have the following resource model.

```
namespace Vendor\Gift\Model\ResourceModel;

class GiftInformation extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('gift_products', 'gift_id');
    }
```

And the following model:

```
namespace Vendor\Gift\Model;

class Gift extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{

    public $giftId;

    public function __construct(    
            $giftId = null
    ){
        $this->giftId = $giftId;
        $this->_init('Vendor\Gift\Model\ResourceModel\GiftInformation');
    }

    }
}
```

When I do

```
$this->_giftFactory = $this->_giftFactory->create(['giftId'=>$this->giftId]);
```

I can use  `$this->_giftFactory->setData([..some data..])` and  `$this->_giftFactory->getData()` methods of the factory, but when I try
 `$this->_giftFactory-save()`, so that I can insert a row in my table "gift_products" I receive the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Call to a member function dispatch() on null in
/magento_root_dir/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php:661 
......
... rest of the stack trace, which just leads to the place where I invoke the save() method.
```

On line 661 in `AbstractModel.php` I have :

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch('model_save_before', ['object' => $this]);
```

What is the problem here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're not declaring the right method in your model.

Instead of

```
__construct()
```

It should be:

```
_construct()
```

With only one underscore.

Then the function should look like this:

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('Vendor\Gift\Model\ResourceModel\GiftInformation');
}
```